# Is it correct to assign a slice_array to another slice_array?

Tags: c++, c++14, llvm, valarray

```
int input[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
std::valarray<int> test(input, sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]));

const std::slice_array<int> s1 = test[std::slice(1, 3, 2)];
const std::slice_array<int> s2 = test[std::slice(0, 3, 1)];

// is it correct to do this?
s1 = s2;

std::valarray<int> temp(s1);
printf("temp[0]=%d  temp[1]=%d temp[2]=%d\n", temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]);
```

Running the code, I got:

```
test: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

s1:     1   3   5

s2:   0 1 2 

s1=s2

s1:     0   0   2     --> 0 1 2 is expected for s1

test: 0 0 2 0 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I'm just wondering if `s1 = s2` is correct to use?

If it is correct to use, then is it safe to say that it is a bug for my old version of LLVM C++ library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can assign one `std::slice_array` to another with [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice_array/operator%3D)

> Assigns the selected elements from sl_arr to the referred to elements of *this.

Also, there's no bug here, the result of `s1 = [0, 0, 2]` is correct.

In your case:

```
test { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
s1        ^     ^     ^
s2     ^  ^  ^
```

Notice that the 1st element referred to by `s2` is 0 which gets assigned to the 1st element of `s1`, which is the 2nd element of `test`.

This newly assigned value then is the 2nd value of `s2` which gets assigned to the 2nd value of `s1`, and so on.

At the end of the assignment, `test` becomes

```
test { 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But if I used GNU C++, I got different results, after s1=s2, I got s1: 0, 1, 2 instead of 0 0 2. I tried clang++ 3.7 and 9.0, I also got 0, 1, 2. so I'm confused with different results. Is there a standard that says in this case, 0,0,2 is correct or 0,1,2 is correct?  Thanks!

Comment: please note that I downloaded the clang from [link](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html). thanks.

Comment: @issac Remove the `const` from the declaration of `s1` and you'll get `0 0 2`. I'm not actually sure why it compiles with `const` at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing it out, removing const, I got consistent result. Thanks!